# Search private resources in ckan

Tags: api, talend, ckan

I have a private resources in a dataset. Using Api to search the private resources, always I get a count 0 resources.
I've use all searching methods and headers like 'include_private' but no is possible to find private resources.
I'm Using CKAN 2.7.
¿What can I do?

Comment: Are you really using Talend ? (you have tagged this question with talend but as I am reading your post I am not sure you are using it). If so, could you add a screenshot of your job ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Talend 5.5. With the component tRESTClient, invoking "MyCKAN"/api/3/action/resource_search

Answer (score 0):

This should work but refer to this answer and comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55688111/3366016

Same goes for 2.7